# Asp.net variables values

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.net in my project.

I Declare a Variable btn_clik, tot at the beginning of Class.

```
 public partial class Table : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public int btn_click = 1, tot = 0;
```

I have two button, Up And Down. When I click Up button btn_click variable want to decrease. And Down Button btn_click variable want to increase.

```
 protected void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            if (btn_click != 1) { btn_click--;}              
 }

 protected void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       if (btn_click < tot) { btn_click++;}               
 }
```

But At the Page load,.. btn_click vale is 1; then I Click Down Button,.. btn_click value is 2. I repeat the Down Button Click,.. But btn_click value is still 2; I Check that with breakpoints. Each Time btn_click Variable is going to 1, At that time of Button Click.

What is the Mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.Net instances do not persist across HTTP requests.
Each requests gets a new instance of your page class.

You need to store the value in session state or viewstate.

Comment: I guess adding "totally" makes something more irrelevant.

Comment: NanDri(Thanks in Tamil Language).

Comment: Where I Can Read the Basic Things of ASP.NET?.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `Session variables` in this context. Replace you code from `session variables to ViewState variables`. @SLaks, I hope you are agreed with this. Obviously this is doing the same job **BUT** with good approach

Below is the sample code...

```
 protected void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (ViewState["btn_click"] == null)
            btn_click = 0;
        else
            btn_click = (int)ViewState["btn_click"];
      if (btn_click != 1) { btn_click--;} 
      ViewState["btn_click"] = btn_click;

 }
```

---

**Check the differences between Session and ViewState below are the References**

[**Session Vs ViewState**](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/35283-Difference-between-Session-ViewState.aspx)